# Passing JavaScript Variables from JavaScript to PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having some problems with my PHP file. So basically I am working on a project that takes two addresses from the user, then it uses javascript to show their route and once they click submit, I want to pass these two variables to PHP file. I researched a lot and found that I would need AJAX call. The problem I am running into is that AJAX call works perfectly, but when I go to PHP file it throws me an error that variables are not defined. Someone, please explain to me what I am doing wrong here.

JavaScript code:

```
 /* ============================================================================================
   Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions
   ==============================================================================================
  */ 
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeControl: false,
      center: {lat: 41.881832, lng: -87.623177},
      zoom: 13
    });

    new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
  }

   /**
    * @constructor
   */
  function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
    this.map = map;
    this.originPlaceId = null;
    this.destinationPlaceId = null;
    this.travelMode = 'DRIVING';
    var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
    var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
    var submit_button = document.getElementById('button-to-submit');
    /*var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');*/
    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        originInput, {placeIdOnly: true});
           var destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        destinationInput, {placeIdOnly: true});

    /*this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', 'WALKING');
    this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', 'TRANSIT');
    this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', 'DRIVING');*/

    this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
    this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');

    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput);
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(submit_button);
    /*this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);*/
  }

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  /* AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupClickListener = function(id, mode) {
    var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    var me = this;
    radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      me.travelMode = mode;
      me.route();
    });
  }; */

  AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(autocomplete, mode) {
    var me = this;
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.place_id) {
        window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
        return;
      }
      if (mode === 'ORIG') {
        me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
      } else {
        me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
      }
      me.route();
    });

  }; 

  AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
    if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
      return;
    }
    var me = this;

    this.directionsService.route({
      origin: {'placeId': this.originPlaceId},
      destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
      travelMode: this.travelMode
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        origin_addr = document.getElementById('origin-input').value;
        //console.log(origin_addr);
        destination_addr = document.getElementById('destination-input').value;
        //console.log(destination_addr);
        //var place_id = document.getElementById('origin-input');
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
     });

  };

  $("#button-to-submit").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
         url: "Database/save-points.php",
         type: "POST", //send it through get method
         data: { 
          origin_address: origin_addr,
          destination_address: destination_addr
          },
          success: function(response) {
        //Do Something
           console.log("Succeed");
           location.href="Database/save-points.php";
          },
          error: function(xhr) {
    //Do Something to handle error
          }
        });  
});
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $origin_address = $_POST['origin_address'];
    $destination_address = $_POST['destination_address'];
    echo $origin_address;
    echo $destination_address;
?>
```

Comment: Please paste your code in the question. Do not use images for that.

Comment: where do 'origin_addr' and 'destination_addr' come from ? where are they set ?

Comment: They are coming from another function in same javascipt file and I already debugged using console.log. They work perfectly fine

Comment: I mean -> data: {  origin_address: origin_addr,  destination_address: destination_addr   } /* seems like there'll be nothing in here, have you checked that vars are properly propagated from the previous state/function ? */

Comment: How can I do that? @OldPadawan

Comment: @GiamPy- I copied code

Comment: Can you update the code in your question adding the other js function ? so we can have a look at it

Comment: @OldPadawan - Done

Comment: can you try to add right after this line : $("#button-to-submit").click(function() { origin_addr = $("#origin-input").val(); /*check if set as -> origin_addr = document.getElementById('origin-input').value; */ destination_addr = $("#destination-input").val(); /**check if set as -> destination_addr = document.getElementById('destination-input').value;*/  /*and then, any result when you check ? */

Comment: @OldPadawan - No it throws me same error

Comment: I have tried the following code with my own API_KEY -> works like a charm, got the vars passed through ajax request and back  from php :) [link to the code](https://pastebin.com/XdLaXzn3) (don't forget to put your KEY back in the code if you want to test it, and let me know, I don't know if it'll fit your needs, and had no power at all to fetch through both my code and yours seeking for any difference... you'll have to do it yourself ^^

Comment: @OldPadawan -  your code definitely works fine. My only question is why isn't it printing those values when I add this function to the end window.location.href="Database/save-points.php"?. I want to redirect my page to this PHP file when button is clicked

Comment: @Dipen : you redirect user to 'Database/save-points.php' in a 'raw' format, without any url parameters, therefore, nothing gets to save-points.php -> empty vars = empty print :)

Comment: Posted the all script with redirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/* maps.php */

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr" dir="ltr">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .controls {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }

  #origin-input,
  #destination-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 200px;
  }

  #origin-input:focus,
  #destination-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
  }

  #mode-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
  }

  #mode-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text"
    placeholder="Enter an origin location">

<input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
    placeholder="Enter a destination location">

<div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
  <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
  <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
  <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>

  <input type="submit" id="button-to-submit" value="SAVE !" />
</div>

<div id="map"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOU_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
  // parameter when you first load the API. For example:

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeControl: false,
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13
    });

    new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
  }

   /**
    * @constructor
   */
  function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
    this.map = map;
    this.originPlaceId = null;
    this.destinationPlaceId = null;
    this.travelMode = 'WALKING';
    var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
    var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
    var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');
    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        originInput, {placeIdOnly: true});
    var destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        destinationInput, {placeIdOnly: true});

    this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', 'WALKING');
    this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', 'TRANSIT');
    this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', 'DRIVING');

    this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
    this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');

    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput);
    this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);
  }

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupClickListener = function(id, mode) {
    var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    var me = this;
    radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      me.travelMode = mode;
      me.route();
    });
  };

  AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(autocomplete, mode) {
    var me = this;
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.place_id) {
        window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
        return;
      }
      if (mode === 'ORIG') {
        me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
      } else {
        me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
      }
      me.route();
    });

  };

  AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
    if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
      return;
    }
    var me = this;

    this.directionsService.route({
      origin: {'placeId': this.originPlaceId},
      destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
      travelMode: this.travelMode
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  };

/************************************/
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#button-to-submit").click(function() {

origin_addr = $("#origin-input").val();
destination_addr = $("#destination-input").val();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "maps.exe.php",
        data: {
        origin_address: origin_addr,
        destination_address: destination_addr
        },
        success: function(response){
        alert(response);
        window.location.href = 'test-resp.php?'+response;
        }
        });
        return false;
        });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

/* maps.exe.php */

```
<?php

$origin_address = $_POST['origin_address'];
$destination_address = $_POST['destination_address'];

echo"origin=$origin_address&destination=$destination_address";

?>
```

/* test-resp.php */

```
<?php

$origin_address = $_GET['origin'];
$destination_address = $_GET['destination'];

echo"[ origin : $origin_address / destination = $destination_address ]";

?>
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example of me passing JS variable to PHP.

JS (`url` and `content` are JS variables) :

```
var data_to_send = {
    filepath: ""+url,
    filecontent: ""+content
};


jQuery.ajax({
    url:"php/dynamic.php",
    data: data_to_send,
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    type:'post',
    timeout:3000//purely optionnal, check jQuery's Doc to learn more about ajax optionnal parameters/settings
});
```

In `dynamic.php` :

```
    <?php

        $vars = serialize($_POST); /*easier access*/

        $file_path = "../".$vars["filepath"];
        $file_content = $var["filecontent"]; /*example of assigning a JS var's value to a PHP var*/
        $fh = fopen($file_path, 'w+') or die("could not open file");
        fwrite($fh, $file_content."\n");
        fclose($fh);

    ?>
```

PS: I use jQuery for POST, I dunno the pure javascript way to do the same :/